# ¿Cómo poner un input en posiciones determinadas de un texto?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Se trata de una aplicación que estoy haciendo en Javascript, HTML y CSS. Para dibujar la interfaz, me he encontrado con el problema siguiente:
Al crear un juego le paso como parámetros, un texto y un nombre, y para ese texto quiero sustituir todos los carácteres "$", por inputs, por ejemplo:

El perro $ quería comer $ pero no había pienso suficiente.

Sería sustituir los caracteres $ por inputs. He probado primeramente a sustituir por otro tipo de carácter, pero me sigue mostrando el texto tal cual.

```
function mostrarHuecos(textoEjercicio){
  $('#mostrarTexto').remove();
  if ($.cookie("pro")){
    var text=textoEjercicio;
    text.replace(/$/g,"__");
    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTexto" class="caja" ><h4>'+ text + '</div>';
    $('#listaEjercicios').append(cadena);
  }
}
```

La idea sería, sustituirlo por los inputs que ya he comentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function mostrarHuecos(textoEjercicio) {
  $('#mostrarTexto').remove();
  if ($.cookie("pro")) {
    var text = textoEjercicio;
    text.innerHTML = text.replace(/$/g, "__");
    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTexto" class="caja" ><h4>' + text + '</div>';
    $('#listaEjercicios').append(cadena);
  }
}
```

La función `replace()` te devuelve un string, no te actualiza el valor del elemento, tienes que cambiarlo con alguna función como `innerHTML` ó `$(elemento).html()`.

Comment: Vale, me ha funcionado simplemente igualando text = text.replace(/$/g, "__"), no me di cuenta que así solo devolvía el string. Ahora, para sustituirlo por un input, ¿se puede con replace también?. Muchas gracias por cierto

Comment: En este caso te funciona porque estas haciendo un append, si vas a cambiar directamente un elemento HTML tendrás que usar esas funciones o sino te lo cambiará como texto. Sí, te debería funcionar igual poniendo un input.

Answer (score 1):

Ya está solucionado, para el que le interesara sería así:

```
function mostrarHuecos(textoEjercicio){
  $('#mostrarTexto').remove();
  if ($.cookie("pro")){
    var text=textoEjercicio;
    var input = '<input type="text" style="width: 55px;">'
    text = text.replace(/@/g, input);
    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTexto" class="caja" ><h4>'+ text + '</div>';
    $('#listaEjercicios').append(cadena);
  }
}
```

Lo he hecho finalmente con el caracter @, porque no me dejaba hacerlo correctamente con el $.

Comment: Mételo dentro de corchetes y te dejará text.replace(/[$]/g, input);

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por la ayuda, es así